# How can I run an asp.net website in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis, subdirectory

So, I have a problem about subfolder and webconfig, I have searched a lot but is's not the common context problem.

Read please all

My website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) points by IIS to this subfolder
website/completed/4/index.aspx

My images are here
website/completed/4/images

When for example I call "/images/example.png" from pages in the root ([www.example.com/index.aspx](http://www.example.com/index.aspx)), works

When I call "/images/example.png" from pages in subfolder ([www.example.com/user/account.aspx](http://www.example.com/user/account.aspx)), works, too

So it's perfect by IIS configurations

When I'm in my other website [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) that points by IIS to the root
and I call the image I have to do like this "/website/completed/4/images/example.png" and works, of course

My problem is about to call this image from these pages

I'm in the page [www.abc.com/website/completed/4/index.aspx](http://www.abc.com/website/completed/4/index.aspx)

I'm in the page [www.abc.com/website/completed/4/user/account.aspx](http://www.abc.com/website/completed/4/user/account.aspx)
I need a solution that allows me to call from both these pages, my image, in this way "/images/example.png"

How can I do?
Thank you very much

Comment: You can put the images folder in the root directory of the project, and then put the image in the images folder, and finally call in this way "~/images/example.png".

Comment: @DingPeng I can't change the structure, there are gonna be images of the clients in website/completed/4 for the completed website template number 4, than 1, 2, 3, 5,.. than I have other section about website/ecommerce.. The structure has to be like this help me pleaseeee

Comment: Please could anyone help me? @DingPeng

Comment: I think you can use URL rewrite, you can rewrite the request of /images/example.png to /website/completed/4/images/example.png.